# jqGrid row limit in pagination

Tags: pagination, jqgrid

My jqGrid code is as below. The pagination grid shows up, but all 500 records are displayed in a single page. I need 10 records per page.

```
jQuery("#Mygrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            autowidth: true,
            page: 1,
            total:10,
            records: 15,
            viewrecords: true,
            pager: '#MyGridPager',
            colNames: [some col names],
            colModel: some col
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify the page size one have to use You should use `rowNum` parameter: `rowNum: 10` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#properties)).

Comment: tried this. Did not work. Tried the below as well:  datatype: "json",
            height: 250,
            autowidth: true,
            page: 5,
            total: 10,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],

Comment: @Learner: Why you removed `pager` parameter? It's required in the same way like `rowNum`. Compare https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/L417gcwf/ and https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/L417gcwf/55/. Parameters `page: 5, total: 10` (or `records`) will be set by jqGrid, you don't need to use it during creating the grid.

Comment: I haven't removed pager param. Tried the same as mentioned in ur link , still doesnt show the pager or the pagerbar itself if pager is set to true rather than  pager: '#MyGridPager'. Also on setting pager: '#MyGridPager' , the bar reads page 1 of 0.

Comment: I also have this part at the end...for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)
            jQuery("#MyGrid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, data[i]);
    }
    jQuery("#MyGrid").setGridParam({ rowNum: 10 }).trigger("reloadGrid");

Comment: @Learner: First of all I posted you jsfiddle demos because you can easy modify it including your code and your test data. If something not works then you should send me the URL of modified demo. It's quick and clear. About your code `for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) jQuery("#MyGrid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, data[i]); } jQuery("#MyGrid").setGridParam({ rowNum: 10 }).trigger("reloadGrid");`. It's the worst way to fill jqGrid, which I know. Instead of that you should just use `data` parameter of jqGrid. Because the input data in your case have the same `data` name then use: `data: data`